# Remove text from toolbar while open search view

Tags: java, android, kotlin, search, toolbar

[image: toolbar image]

I don't want this text while click on search in toolbar.

Below is my menu item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

This is my `onCreateOptionsMenu` in Activity

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
        val search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = search.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.queryHint = "Search in everywhere "
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
//                adapter.filter.filter(newText)
                return true
            }
        })
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

Very confuse with this. need some help. Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: at first place use             app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
.....show more code how you handle  it in your activity or fragment

Comment: There is no code in activity or fragment. some thing that change is in menu file.

Comment: update your gradle files to the last version

Comment: @Mohmmaed-Amleh it's already upto date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `searchView.maxWidth = Integer.MAX_VALUE`  this line in my code and it work for me.

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
        val search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = search.actionView as SearchView
        
        searchView.maxWidth  = Integer.MAX_VALUE  // add this line to your code.
        
        searchView.queryHint = "Search in everywhere "
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
//                adapter.filter.filter(newText)
                return true
            }
        })
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
toolbar.setTitle("");
toolbar.setSubtitle("");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. but this will remove my title at all. I only remove my title while search view is open.

Comment: add this line when search view open getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

Comment: No it's manage from menu file. so I can't get it in activity. there is changes in menu file with showAsAction this is not solution for me.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.